# SAP Websphere integration with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Could any body please advise me or suggest how to integrate SAP Websphere messaging services integration with SharePoint Online?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: question is to broad..you need to tell what kind of integration..explain your business use case...

Comment: I just need to get the data from SAP websphere and display in SharePoint online.